# VBA - IE Nest selection item with ID

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Trying to select the Export button below which has an ID and name. I know I can getelementbyID but not sure how to then specify to further drill into the getattribute("name") because the getelementbyID wil only return 1 value, not an array

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `getElementsByName("export")(0)`

Comment: Thanks Nathan - worked!

Comment: i've put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Mturks83

`getElementsByName("export")(0)` the first part will give you the array of elements called `export` the `(0)` gives you the first.

Answer (score 1):

It is faster to use `querySelector` than `getElementsBy`.

For example, just got direct with an attribute = value selector

```
ie.document.querySelector("[name=export]")
```

If more than one then add the parent td element id

```
ie.document.querySelector("#bottomButtonRow [name=export]")
```

Reading:

1. [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)